# How do I make a function for cancel button which when button is clicked unchecks all buttons that I have checked?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I have made a menu which consists of checkbuttons which are created by adding values to a list, so to be precise if I want to add a new item on the menu all I need to do is to put something in the list and checkbutton will be created through while loop. I landed on a problem here, I want to make a cancel button which unchecks all the selected buttons but due to variable option in checkbutton being same for all the buttons because there is only one while loop for creating them all my buttons get selected when I press on one.

Note I do not want to use `deselect()` option, I am trying to make it this way. Typical error I get is:

> Ponisti[p] = tkinter.IntVar()
> IndexError: list assignment index out of range,

Or it does that thing where it selects all when I press one button.
So all in all, I am trying to make the variable in checkbutton change for each new button I add so I can select them independently.

My piece of code is given as an example, I hope you can get a grasp of it and a grasp of my idea.

Piece of code:

```py
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
Array =[]

p=0
Ponisti =[]
while p != len(Meni):
     Ponisti[p] = tkinter.IntVar()
     p=p+1

def cancel():
    f=0
    for i in Array:
       Ponisti[f].set('0')
       f=f+1

while j != len(Meni):
    items = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, text=Meni[j], onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
   
canceldugme = tkinter.Button(frame1,text="Cancel",command=cancel)
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a `for` loop instead of using that `while` loop? Also there are a lot of undefined variables in your code.

Comment: I am not able to use it because the menu consists of integer and string together, basically it is two lists one consists of names of food and other of prices and when i connect them i make them as checkbuttons in a while loop.Now i want to make a cancel button which unselects the selected items but the button has only one variable option and when i put my cancel function, that has IntVar() and set('0'), in that variable option all my items get selected when i click on one.

Comment: You can replace the first `while` loop with `for p in range(len(Meni))` and the second one with `for j in range(len(Meni))`

Comment: So now i can put Ponisti list as variable in checkbutton?Because i am trying to set those variables and add a cancel function as command in my cancel button.

Comment: Ok now i put that Ponisti as a variable in checkbutton but again it selects every button once i press on one because checkbutton is in while loop that makes them as long as i add new items on my menu list.```for j in range(len(Meni)):
    items = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, text=Meni[j], onvalue=1, offvalue=0,variable=Ponisti)```

Comment: @CupidONO Look at [this](https://pastebin.com/qf5T5QVh) I think I simplified your code.

Comment: ```def cancel():
    f=0
    for i in Array:
       Ponisti[f].set('0')
       f=f+1   canceldugme = tkinter.Button(frame1,text="Cancel",command=cancel)``` And it does the same, selects every button due to variable not changing for all buttons.

Comment: Let me get this right, you want to create a bunch of checkbuttons, which are all bound to their own variable and when you press a button you want to uncheck them all by resetting the variables and not using the `deselect`  method. Correct?

Comment: Yes exactly but they all get bound to one variable so they all get selected, cancel button works tho.

Comment: @CupidONO You don't pass in the `IntVar` to the `tkinter.Checkbutton`. Is that on purpose? It looks like a bug to me

Comment: I just realized that cancel doesnt work also, and you can pass IntVar or StringVar in checkbutton.

Comment: @CupidONO Add `variable=Ponisti[j]` to `items = tkinter.Checkbutton(...)`

Comment: It works, thank you so much for your help i am so happy right now!Can i give you some +rep if it is possible, both of you i am new to stackoverflow?

Comment: @CupidONO I will write an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def reset():
    for var in variables:
        var.set(0)

menu = [str(i) for i in range(8)]

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

variables = [tk.IntVar(0) for _ in range(len(menu))]

length = len(menu) // 2
for i, var in enumerate(variables):
    row, col = divmod(i, length)
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(frame, variable=var, text=menu[i])
    checkbutton.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="w")

reset_button = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", command=reset)
reset_button.pack(side="right")

root.mainloop()
```

Basically you want to create a list of variables and for each variable create a new button that is bound to it. When you call the `reset` function, all you have to do is iterate over your variables and reset their value.

I put the checkbuttons in a frame so you can use the `grid` method, since it seeems you want to lay them out in a grid fashion. The reason for using a frame is that you can't mix `grid` and `pack` for the same window. Both `frame` and `reset_button` are placed using `pack()`, and the checkuttons inside the frame can then be placed using `grid()`.